# Redirect search engines to specific route, ie. 'mydomain.com/somepath'

Tags: search, next.js, seo, url-routing, appdomain

I have a nextjs webapp.

I want the main application to run on the index route: `...mydomain.com/`.

But I also want to have a landing page at route: `...mydomain.com/mylandingpage`.

---

The question I have is, how do I tell Bing, Google, DuckDuckGo etc, that the 'page of interest' is `... mydomain.com/mylandingpage` and not `... mydomain.com/`?

Can I use a robots.txt file, or is there some special way of linking the pages, or using 307 redirects?

Answer (score 0):

google at request headers (referer)
check if the referer is one of searchEngine websites,
if it's make a redirect

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use a canonical tag in your index appointing to the landing page, something like this:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/mylandingpage">
```